# Running NCover from code

Tags: nunit, code-coverage, ncover, ncover-explorer

Is it possible to run NCover automatically from code instead of running NCover manually or via  command line?

Here is the scenario, I have written a few tests, I execute all the tests and after the tests are completed, NCover should run automatically for that particular test project and store the coverage report as an XML in a location.

Is this possible to do? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Running NCover from the command line was the only option with NC3. When we updated NC4 the default works like this --> you create a project, the NCover service watches for a process to start that meets the match rules defined in the project, and then collects coverage on it.

This doc may be of some help: http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/desktop/user-guide/coverage_scenarios/how_do_i_collect_data_from_nunit

If you have more questions, please reach out to us at support@ncover.com.